# Integer overflow despite large enough type?

Tags: c++, overflow, addition

A bit of code I'm working on has stumped me. I appear to be dealing with integer overflow, which I admit I haven't encountered before, but I've tried several things to fix it and none of them have worked so far. I'm using MSVC++ 2010.

The relevant code is very simple, and is as follows:

```
int64_t numerator = cdfVal * (maxIntensity - 1);
```

This is failing for me for the case where cdfVal (this is just a value read from an array, nothing fancy) is 8667003 and maxIntensity - 1 is 255. A simple calculation shows that the solution ought to be 2210085765, whereas I'm getting the value -2084881531. I understand that this is a case of integer overflow, but I thought 64 bits would be large enough to hold the result. I switched to uint64_t, but in that case I got a result that was twenty digits long, which is obviously incorrect!
I've tried using Boost's multiprecision integers but got similar results with those as well.

I feel like this is something really simple I'm missing.

Comment: what types `cdfVal` and `maxIntensity` are?

Comment: Both just normal `int`s.

Comment: `int` * `int` = `int`

Comment: The promotion to `int64_t` is after the multiplication. Convert at least one of the operands to `int64_t` (ideally both), before the operation. Or just use `int64_t` operands in the first place.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I'll remember that in future.

Comment: @PiotrS.: I wish you would have made that an answer. You deserve the rep.

Comment: @FredLarson: today's limit already exceeded :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `numerator` is irrelevant to the type in which the expression is evaluated. C++ evaluates expressions in the "biggest type of the operands involved" (disregarding some details).

You mentioned `cdfVal` and `maxIntensity` are both of type `int`. `1` is of type `int` as well. Which means the whole expression is evaluated in type `int` (and overflows there). The resulting `int` is then promoted to `int64_t` and assigned to `numerator`.

If you want to get around this, either declare at least one of the variables as `int64_t`, or cast at least one of them to the desired type. Like this:

```
int64_t numerator = static_cast<int64_t>(cdfVal) * (maxIntensity - 1);
```

To be consistent and a little more explicit, you can of course cast both:

```
int64_t numerator = static_cast<int64_t>(cdfVal) * static_cast<int64_t>(maxIntensity - 1);
```